# Using Get-ADGroup & Get-Groupmember when in multiple Groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So im trying to return a report that will list each user and each group they are in using -Filter "name-like '*BLAH*'"

the user may be apart multiple "BLAH" groups but no more than 3. How can i get an output like?
Member | Group1 | Group2 | Group3

I tried the below but not quite what i need

```
$adgroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*BLAH*'" | sort name

$data = foreach ($adgroup in $adgroups) {
    $members = $adgroup | get-adgroupmember |select name| sort name
    foreach ($member in $members) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Members = $member
            Group   = $adgroup.name
                    }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is what i get when using @Adam Luniewski solution

Comment: You could add `-Properties MemberOf` to your `Get-ADUser`command to get the groups the user is meber of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just watch out if you have StrictMode set in your script, it might throw an error if $usrgrp count is less than 3, then you'd have to modify this part.

```
# get a list of all users and groups in two columns
$dat = @(Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*BLAH*'" -PipelineVariable group | Get-ADGroupMember | select @{n='UserName';e={$_.name}},@{n='GroupName';e={$group.name}})

# for each user in a list add group fields
$dat | select UserName -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    $usrgrp = @($dat | where username -eq $_.UserName | sort GroupName);
    [pscustomobject]@{
        UserName=$_.Username; 
        Group1=$usrgrp[0].GroupName; 
        Group2=$usrgrp[1].GroupName; 
        Group3=$usrgrp[2].GroupName; 
    };
}
```

Comment: how can i get each group into a column like Member | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$adgroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*BLAH*'" | Sort-Object Name
$data = ForEach ($adgroup in $adgroups){
  $adgroup | get-adgroupmember | Select-Object @{n='Members';e={$_}},@{n='Group';e={(Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf}}
}
```

Here Get-ADUser is used to retrieve user group memberships (first said @Olaf) then I used calculated properties to format the output.